# ViewContainerRef & createEmbeddedView clarification?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'vcrdi',
  template: `
    <template #tpl>
       <h1>ViewContainerRef DI</h1>
    </template>

  `,
})
export class VcrDIComponent {
  @ViewChild('tpl') tpl;

  constructor(private _vcr: ViewContainerRef) {console.log(_vcr)}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.tpl);
  }
}
```

This component is used in the main `my-app` element as :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
        <vcrdi></vcrdi>
  `,
})
```

The Ctor at the `vcrdi` component is injected with `_vcr: ViewContainerRef` so now the container is the actual `<vcrdi>...</vcrdi>` element.

This is the rendered DOM:

[image]

Notice that the `h1` was inserted AFTER the `ViewContainerRef` (which is the `vcrdi` element)

Let's go to the [*docs*](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html) :

> `createEmbeddedView(templateRef: TemplateRef<C>, context?: C, index?:
>   number) : EmbeddedViewRef<C>`
>   Instantiates an Embedded View based on the templateRef and **inserts it into this container** at the specified
>   index.
>
> If index is not specified, the new View **will be inserted as the last
>   View in the container**.

Well, if `vcrdi` is the container ref , then I didn't see *anything* injected into it  :

```
<vcrdi>
   // If vcrdi ^  is the container  , then why does this section  empty ?
</vcrdi>
```

**Question:**

The docs states that something is in injected to the container.
But if `vcrdi`is the container , and we see that nothing is injected  - but appended  -  then -  What am I missing here ?

[**Demo PLNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/IBLqFoZNO7r1eEvNR1k8?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

For the `vcrdi` component, the view container is `<my-app></my-app>`.

Explanation and examples: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-understanding-viewcontainerref-acc183f3b682